# Spiral Iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, iteration

I need an Algorithm that I will use to scan pixels out from the center. Problem is with different lengths and sizes, it sometimes can't get to the position (See Image below blue part).

[image: Image1]

To illustrate the problem more I will show the example output:

[image: Image2]

If you compare the pictures you will notice that it goes in a spiral and the outputs match with a regular for loop and obviously the problem that it doesn't print the blue part correctly

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
int arrSize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int width = 5;
int height = 3;

void normal2DArray() {
    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            std::cout << std::to_string(x) << "," << std::to_string(y) << " = " << std::to_string(arr[index]) << "\n";
            index++;
        }
    }
}

int convertToInex(int x, int y) {
    int left = x * y; // elements to the left
    int right = (width - x) * y; // elements to the right
    return left + right + x;
}

void spiralArray() {
    // calculate middle point, which is also the start point
    int x = round((float)width / 2) - 1;
    int y = round((float)height / 2) - 1;

    int direction = 0; // 0=right, 1=up, 2=left, 3=down
    int turnCounter = 1;
    int numSteps = 1;
    int step = 1;
    int index;

    while (true) {

        index = convertToInex(x, y); // defines the index position in arr
        std::cout << std::to_string(x) << "," << std::to_string(y) << " = " << std::to_string(arr[index]) << "\n";

        switch (direction) {
        case 0: x++; break;
        case 1: y--; break;
        case 2: x--; break;
        case 3: y++; break;
        }
        index = convertToInex(x, y);

        if (step % numSteps == 0) {
            direction = (direction + 1) % 4;
            turnCounter++;
            if (turnCounter % 2 == 0) numSteps++;
        }
        step++;
        if (step > arrSize) break;
    }
}

void main() {
    std::cout << "Output of Normal 2D Array:\n";
    normal2DArray();

    std::cout << "\n"; // better spacing

    std::cout << "Output of Spiral Array:\n";
    spiralArray();
}
```

I tried to keep the code as simple and small as possible. It should be ready to import and use.
And yes I already searched for my answer online but I didn't find anything that covered up the problem here nor had a similar setup like I have(1D arr and combined 2D array WIDTH/HEIGHT) and for sure not in c++.

❗ Also I need a Solution that works with all widths and heights and arr sizes and also works for any side ❗

I hope you can provide me with helpful answers and would be grateful with good and fast algorithm implementations/optimizations

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the replies in this Thread. I decided to go with the solution from [@ldog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177931/ldog) for now even though I'm not completely satisfied with it.

Here are the edited code parts:

```
    int failcounter = 0;
    while (true) {
    index = convertToInex(x, y); // defines the index position in arr
    if (index < 0 || index > arrSize) failcounter++;
    else std::cout << std::to_string(x) << "," << std::to_string(y) << " = " << std::to_string(arr[index]) << "\n";

// unchanged code inbetween

if (step > arrSize + failcounter) break;
```

Comment: What sequence do you want for that array? If you start from 8 there is no good answer.

Comment: Start from 7 or 9

Comment: @Beta I just want an algorithm that goes out from the center and gets every pixel. It doesn't have to be this Spiral one but I thought it would be the most efficient one

Comment: @KU99 this will not fix the issue. Also the whole point of this is to scan out from the center and 8 is the most centered one

Comment: Then *what sequence do you want?* Try it. Try it with a pencil, starting from 8. There is no good answer.

Comment: @Beta they don't need to connect. It just has to detect that it's outside the array size (in that case -1) and don't scan them and find the next continue point. So it would continue like this: 5, 1, 6, 11

Comment: " It doesn't have to be this Spiral one but I thought it would be the most efficient one": this is not an acceptable answer. The center is not even defined in case of even sizes, you need to be more specific. And there is no efficiency issue here, every traversal rule will take roughly the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> @Beta they don't need to connect. It just has to detect that it's outside the array size (in that case -1) and don't scan them and find the next continue point. So it would continue like this: 5, 1, 6, 11

it seems you don't care that the spiral goes "out-of-bounds". In this case, the trivial answer is, embed the shapes that have no spiral in one that is always guaranteed to have one.

Thus if your input rectangle is `N x M`, then embed it in a rectangle of size `max(M,N) x max(M,N)`, solve the problem in the latter, and when printing just ignore non-existent numbers in the original problem. Your printed sequence then will always be unique up to how the embedding occurs. The most reasonable embedding would try to center the smaller rectangle as much as possible in the larger rectangle, but this is up to you.

In this case you don't need an algorithm as you can compute everything analytically if you care to do the book-keeping and figure out the formulas involved.

Comment: Yeah that is a simple solution I have thought about aswell. But that would mean I would have a bigger for loop than there are actual pixels in the array. Which could lead up to a few hundred of unnecessary checks which could be prevented with a smart algorithm. Since I care about speed and performance I want to choose the better options even if it's more work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last paragraph, this does *not* require an algorithm, but a forumla instead, which means you should be able to implement it in O(1) time per item you want to compute values for (O(n) total time.)

Answer (score 0):

You can hit a dead end (meaning exit the grid) in four spots. In each case, jump to the next live pixel you would have reached, if any live cells remain.

You can do this fairly easily by keeping track of the four corners you've visited furthest from the starting pixel. Using compass coords and N for up, these are the NE, NW, SW, and SE extremes visited.

If you hit a dead end going N from the NE pixel, jump to the pixel one to the left of the NW pixel and set the movement direction to down. If that is also a dead end, jump to one below the SW pixel and set the movement direction to right. Etc... When all four corners and dead ends then you're done.